# What is the difference between "Allocable Resource" and "Container" in Python?

Tags: python, containers, theory

I'm studying data structures.
I already know that Python containers are: List, Tuple, Set and Dictionary.

In a Python quiz question there was a question in a had to identify which of the folllowing classes are the one that overloads a given list of methods.

But I don't understand the concept of Allocable resource in Python. Is it referring to stack, queue, binary tree?

So, I used dir() in order to dig inside each class and find out if they have or not the methods indicated in the question.

```
    """A classs overloads the following methods. Which of the following best describes objects
of this class?

__len__
__contains__
__getitem__
__setitem__

A) Generator
B) Iterator
C) Numeric
D) Allocable resource
E) Container
"""
# A) Generator
"""Is not a class"""
# B) Iterator
"""
dir(iter) = 
['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', 
'__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__',
 '__lt__', '__module__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__', 
 '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__self__', '__setattr__', 
'__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__text_signature__']"""
# C) Numeric
"""dir(25) = 
['__abs__', '__add__', '__and__', '__bool__', '__ceil__', '__class__', '__delattr__', 
'__dir__', '__divmod__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__float__', '__floor__', '__floordiv__', 
'__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getnewargs__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__index__',
 '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__int__', '__invert__', '__le__', '__lshift__', '__lt__',
  '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__neg__', '__new__', '__or__', '__pos__', '__pow__', '__radd__',
   '__rand__', '__rdivmod__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rfloordiv__', 
   '__rlshift__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__ror__', '__round__', '__rpow__', '__rrshift__', 
   '__rshift__', '__rsub__', '__rtruediv__', '__rxor__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__',
    '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__truediv__', '__trunc__', '__xor__', 'bit_length', 
    'conjugate', 'denominator', 'from_bytes', 'imag', 'numerator', 'real', 'to_bytes']"""
# D) Allocable resource
"""???"""
# E) Container
"""Python's general purpose built-in containers, dict , list , set , and tuple """
"""dir(list) = 
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dir__',
 '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', 
 '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', 
 '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', 
 '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__'
 , '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'append', 'clear', 
 'copy', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']"""
```

Comment: What's the context? Where did you find that terms?

Comment: You may need to give us more context for how "allocable resource" is defined. Generally, for a process, it would include all available memory and which is available for python to use as objects. So containers are allocable resources.... until you run out of memory.

Comment: I don't think "allocable resource" is a standard term, at least not a python specific one. A *container* would be any object that is meant to be used to *contain* other objects. This does include `list`, `tuple`, `set`, and `dict`, but more built-in and non-built in ones as well. If you had a stack, a queue or a binary tree they would also be considered containers.

Comment: Hi @Klaus D. it is from a question in a Python quiz

Comment: I edited my question guys, I added more information about my work.

Comment: If you look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html you will see it fits the interface of Container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is that an Allocable resource is an ambiguous term in Python and that Python containers are the ones that have availability to the methods described in the question.